# cant fetch elements from oneTomany relation in angular (backend spring boot)

Tags: javascript, angular, spring, spring-boot, angular-material

I have 2 entities: Post and Comments and i wanna display all comments by post

Entity Post

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Post {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idPost;
    
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdAt;
    private String content;
     
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      @JsonIgnore
      private List<Comment> comments= new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();


}
```

And entity Comment

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity

public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idComment;
    private String content;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "postIdPost", referencedColumnName = "idPost")
    private Post post;
    
    
}
```

and this is in angular

```
import { User } from "./user";
import { Comment } from "./comment";
import { Like } from "./like";
export class Post {
    idPost!: number;
    user!:User;
    createdAt!:Date;
    content!:string;
    photo!:string;
    comments!: Comment[];
    likes:Like[]=[];
}
```

when i try to display comments by post it never displayed even when i try to access to comments length by {{posts.comments.length}} it shows nothing

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let p of posts">
            <div class="card" >
              <div> p.content </div>
             .
             .
             .
 <ul class="comment-wrap list-unstyled" *ngFor="let com of p.comments   ">
  <p class="small mb-0">{{com.content}}.</p>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot from your network tab of the actual response payload, that is returned from your angular HTTP call?

Answer (score 0):

You can try change the fetch strategy to **fetch=FetchType.EAGER**:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Comment> comments= new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

Comment: EAGER gives me this error
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Comment: Can you try use Set<Comment> instead of List? If you use Set, you have to implement the Comparable interface in your Comment class and define compareTo() method.

Comment: what can i write in compareTo method ??
@Override
 public int compareTo(Comment o) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 0;
 }

Comment: @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return this.idComment.compareTo(((Comment) o).idComment);
    }

Comment: @JsonIgnore
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval=true)

   private Set<Comment> comments  = new HashSet<>();
 public class Comment implements Comparable<Comment>{
...
}

still the same problem nothing displayed and when i change it to EAGER i got this error "java.lang.StackOverflowError\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL"

Comment: Are you doing the display in java or angular? Maybe the problem is in the angular code?

Comment: in angular i dont know where is the problem everything is fine in my front bro

Comment: Try to display in the Java Console, to find where is the problem.

Comment: i think the problem from @JsonIgnore but when i delete this annotation i faced a new problem at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std

Comment: fixed bro i changed @JsonIgnore to @JsonManagedReference("post") in entity post and  @JsonBackReference("post") in Comment entity thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

this is all post api GET
[image]

and this is get allcomment api
[image]